# How can I load an image directly into the Windows clipboard from the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, images, clipboard

My dad asked me how he could script the pasting/inclusion of images in various applications.  I'm sure I could script out some quick `<img src=...` HTML but I believe he's also looking to do this in Windows GUI applications like Word or Outlook.

So, how could I script a process with the following inputs and outputs:

1. `load_image_into_clipboard_script.cmd sample_file.jpg`
2. Clipboard now contains the aforementioned image file, just as if I'd e.g. opened it in Paint and done a *Select All* -> *Copy*.

I noticed there's a `clip.exe` utility with Vista/Win2003 and up; perhaps that will be a useful intermediary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To copy an image into the clipboard, use in the script the tool [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) with the copyimage action :

```
nircmd.exe clipboard copyimage "image-file"
```

However, to cause any application whatsoever to paste the clipboard image is much harder.

Comment: I set up a quick two-step copy and notification process and then hid it behind a Windows shortcut I can invoke with ctrl-shift-alt-S: `nircmd.exe clipboard copyimage "filename.JPG"`
`msg dpritchett Signature loaded into clipboard!`

Comment: When I do this with png I get a black background instead of transparent. Any solutions?

Comment: @Mark: Get in touch with [NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/contact-new.html).